# "augmented by the way that" means...?

Tags: meaning

I'm new here, and I would like to ask for your help.

I'm translating an American article about a certain theatre piece, and there's a phrase that I can't understand  properly.

"Music, song, dance, video and other sounds and images make up the work; the impression is of many short takes that add up to more than so many bytes, **augmented by the way that** Baryshnikov’s own performance history and identity are featured front and center."

My question is about the phrase "augmented by the way that". Does it mean that 
a) it is increased, enlarged because of the fact that Baryshnikov's performance history and identity are featured front and center, or
b) it is increased, enlarged by the manner in which Baryshnikov's own performance history and identity are featured front and center, or
c) some other thing?

Many thanks in advance! :)

Comment: And I'd add "... so many more bytes, ..."  Is this talking about file size?  Isn't the word bites

Comment: Yes, that's about file size (metaphorically). My English-Russian dictionary says "bytes", as far as I understand a "bite" is the act of biting smth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very perceptive question that identifies a subtle ambiguity. I have read it many times and now believe that the ambiguity cannot be resolved. A parallel might be "She crossed the road, helped by the way he held her arm." Even in this simple case the ambiguity remains: it may be the holding or the manner of the helping. Similiarly in your example, it may be the featuring that augments, or it may be the manner of featuring.

As the fact of featuring includes the manner of featuring (but not vice versa), one might expect some extra text to identify if the manner of featuring is intended, rather than the simple case of the fact of featuring. But this is digging hard for niceties.

Comment: As I need it for translation purposes only, not for a paper on linguistics, I think this ambiguity is not such a problem.